# EditorJS rendered blocks flashing

Tags: reactjs, editorjs

I am retrieving data from my back end and using it to render the blocks within my EditorJS instance (Utilizing react-editor-js). However, the text flashes in the editor.

```
<ReactEditorJS value={props.process.process_doc} tools={EDITOR_JS_TOOLS}/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Probably something related to that component (any component above) is changing (or is not memoized) which causes rerendering, you can try to track that with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@welldone-software/why-did-you-render

Comment: Turns out it was an infinite loop spawning from the useEffect function I was calling.